# format year-month to POSIXct

Tags: r, date

I have some data in year-month form that I want to format for graphing in `ggplot`.

```
date <- c("2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-06", "2016-07", "2016-08", 
"2016-09", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12")
```

I was using `parsedate::parse_date`, but since updating R it no longer functioning.

I have looked at

[Format Date (Year-Month) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916503/format-date-year-month-in-r)

`as.yearmon` works fine but it doesn't format to POSIXct which I need for `ggplot`. Other formatting such as `as.POSIXct` and `strptime` are giving NAs or errors.

Note: I don't mind if the first of the month gets added to the "year-mo" format.

Comment: `as.Date(paste0(date,'-01'))`

Comment: `lubridate::parse_date_time(date, "%Y-%m")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a FAQ:  a *date* is comprised of day, month and year.  You are missing one part.  So by adding *a* day, say, '-01', you can impose the missing string structure and parse. Or you can use a more tolerant parser:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anydate("2017-06")
[1] "2017-06-01"
R>
```

Which works for your data too:

```
R> date
 [1] "2016-03" "2016-04" "2016-05" "2016-06"
 [5] "2016-07" "2016-08" "2016-09" "2016-10"
 [9] "2016-11" "2016-12"
R> anydate(date)
 [1] "2016-03-01" "2016-04-01" "2016-05-01"
 [4] "2016-06-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-08-01"
 [7] "2016-09-01" "2016-10-01" "2016-11-01"
[10] "2016-12-01"
R>
```

Lastly, your request for *POSIXct* type is still short an hour, minute and second. But by the same principle:

```
R> anytime(date)
 [1] "2016-03-01 CST" "2016-04-01 CDT"
 [3] "2016-05-01 CDT" "2016-06-01 CDT"
 [5] "2016-07-01 CDT" "2016-08-01 CDT"
 [7] "2016-09-01 CDT" "2016-10-01 CDT"
 [9] "2016-11-01 CDT" "2016-12-01 CST"
R>
```

These two functions return proper `Date` and `POSIXct` types, respectively.

Comment: That's really helpful; does this imply, however, that every *POSIXct* item **has** to have all these attributes? Asking since I was looking at [rounding a POSIX date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325631/round-a-posix-date-posixct-with-base-r-functionality) earlier & understood that one can drop the hour etc when rounding for days (`round (X, "days")`. Is that false, or would  the result no longer be a valid *POSIX* date item?

Comment: How would you define a point in time lacking hours, minutes and seconds?   Yes, converters exists but the _set missing values to zero_.