# R: Date conversion with year and month only

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
201601
201602
201603
```

Is there anyway I can read this items as Date?

So far I've tried `as.Date("201602",format = "%Y%m")` but I gets `NA`

Comment: You might want to add date as well to make it as actual date. `as.Date(paste0("201602", "01"),format = "%Y%m%d")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting year and month ("yyyy-mm" format) to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date) Or [Format Date (Year-Month) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916503/format-date-year-month-in-r) Or [Convert month year to a date in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697399/convert-month-year-to-a-date-in-r)

Comment: I did that, I was hoping for another solution.

Comment: Go through the links shared, that might be helpful.

Comment: Try package anytime